# How to remove scitific notation from matrix python

Tags: python, matrix, printing, int

I have a Matrix looking like this:

```
[  3.32900000e+01   3.32300000e+01   3.32300000e+01   3.32900000e+01
   3.32300000e+01   3.32900000e+01   3.32900000e+01   3.32900000e+01
   3.33300000e+01   3.32900000e+01   3.33300000e+01   3.32900000e+01
   3.33300000e+01   3.33300000e+01   3.33700000e+01   3.33300000e+01
   3.33300000e+01   3.33300000e+01   3.33300000e+01   3.33700000e+01
   3.33700000e+01   3.33700000e+01   3.33700000e+01   0.00000000e+00
   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09
   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09
   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09
   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09
   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09
   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09   1.37646006e+09
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
```

What is the best way to remove the scientific Notation in python?

I have read that it is with:

```
 np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

However this did not change the results.

This is my code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import sys

 np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

 COLUMN_NUM = 4
 datos = np.genfromtxt('a.csv', delimiter=',')[2:]

 datos = np.pad(datos, (0, COLUMN_NUM - len(datos) % COLUMN_NUM), 'constant')
 ds= datos.reshape((-1, COLUMN_NUM))

 print ds

 m = ds.mean(axis=1)

 print "Promedio ", m


 results = np.zeros(shape=(len(datos)))

 for x in range(0, len(datos)):
    tiempo = (((x*1.)/COLUMN_NUM) + 1376460059)
    results[x] = tiempo

 results = np.pad(results, (0, COLUMN_NUM - len(results) % COLUMN_NUM), 'constant')
 results2 = results.reshape((-1, COLUMN_NUM))

 conca = np.concatenate((datos, results))
 print "Concatenate \n", conca
```

Please help me. I have tried for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point precision can be set for numpy arrays like so:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
```

Comment: Thanks but i have try it and I still get the scientific notation looking like this:  3.329e+01   3.323e+01   3.323e+01 . . . and so on. Any other way around this?